# Launch Python Script Terminal Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, terminal, raspberry-pi

I just bought a raspberry pi and I want to launch a python script from terminal. How can I do that?

Comment: Be warned about question that are too broad and try to show what you already did. On a side note, there is also http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

You either start your python interpreter using your scripts name as argument:

```
$ python script.py
```

Or you begin your script with

```
#!/bin/python3
```

make it executable by:

```
$ chmod u+x script.py
```

and start it directly from the shell

```
$ ./script.py
```

Or you could start your python interpreter and load your script interactively.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you open a new terminal window and you enter this:

```
$ python script.py
```

Comment: I'd get rid of that dollar sign. Not all prompts end with it and if you're saying that OP should "enter this", they may literally type it all out.